# Opto-coupler IC internal voltage drop

Tags: fpga, opto-isolator

I have a circuit where an 12 bit ADC IC is outputting 5V logic levels, which are going to be read by an FPGA inputs. The FPGA voltage is 3.3V so the 5V outputs from the ADC chip will switch the 3.3V to the FPGA through opto-couplers.

I am using ILD74 opto-coupler IC's and have attached it's datasheet. It is uses NPN transistor outputs.

My question is what will be the voltage dropped across the collector-emitter of the NPN transistor? Can I expect it to be approx 0.6V?

The reason I ask is that I can't lose the 0.6V from the 3.3V input to the FPGA. Also the FPGA inputs are pulled down with resistors so I want the inputs to be active high.

Thanks everyone!

[ILD74 datasheet pdf](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83640/ild74.pdf)

**EDIT**

I am just thinking, would it be a better idea to connect the 3.3V FPGA inputs on high side switching and let the opto-couplers do the switching so the FPGA has a strong 3.3V and 0V levels. And then just invert the 12 bit inputs on the FPGA hardware?

Comment: Do you need the isolation? If not, any standard level shifter will do a much better job. Otherwise digital isolators would likely be a better choice

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yeah isolation is preferred as there are 2 different power supplies used. The FPGA's internal 3.3V and a bench top power supply for the 5V. Never heard of a digital isolator. I will take a look.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I have edited part of my question.

Comment: _"I can't lose the 0.6V from the 3.3V input to the FPGA"_ - why not? How much voltage can you lose?

Comment: You could simply look up VceSAT in the datasheet you linked.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I didn't check the FPGA input voltage thresholds but would like to keep it at 3.3V

Comment: @BrianDrummond Oh I didn't see it on the datasheet, that's why I asked. My mistake! I see it is around 0.3V and max 0.5V. If you want to leave an answer I will accept it

Comment: Which FPGA are you using? What value are the pull-down resistors?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It's a Nexys A7-100t development FPGA board. I don't know what value the internal pull resistors are, and if it doesn't have any I was going to add some on the external circuit that I built